# Working around the static type property of C++

Tags: c++

Consider this piece of code

```
template<typename T>
void call_me(const T& arg) {
}

template<int i>
struct custom_type {
};


void foo(int i)
{
  switch (i) {
  case 0:
    call_me( custom_type<0>() );
    break;
  case 1:
    call_me( custom_type<1>() );
    break;
  case 2:
    call_me( custom_type<2>() );
    break;
  default:
    break;
  }
}
```

The switch statement is incomplete in the sense of what it is meant to do, i.e. to work for all integers not just the few explicitly mentioned above. C++ won't allow a statement like `custom_type<i>` because `i` is not a constant expression. (..and I can't change the argument to the function `foo` to be a constant expression). Also I would not like to use an external code generator which generates a huge switch statement and feeds it back into source code..

Is there any way in C++/11/14/17 that would allow for writing the function call to `call_me` in an elegant way, or is the answer just, 'no, C++ is statically typed.'?

Comment: It is impossible because function parameter  `i` is determined at runtime. But maybe if you explained the actual problem you're trying to solve with this people might come up with some good ideas.

Comment: If `i` is not known at compile time, it should be a constructor parameter, not a template parameter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this should work, with the addition of the special case call_me_t<0>

```
template <int N>
struct call_me_t
{
   static void exec(int i)
   {
       if (i < N)
           call_me_t<N-1>::exec(i) ;
       else if (i == N)
           call_me(custom_type<N>()) ;
   }
} ;

template<>
struct call_me_t<0>
{
   static void exec(int i)
   {
     call_me(custom_type<0>()) ;
   }
};


void foo(int i)
{
    call_me_t<10>::exec(i) ; // 10 is maximum value in switch
}
```

Comment: Using the numerical template constant recursively is a neat idea

Comment: It won't work in this form because the `i<N` check is a runtime check. So the compiler will never stop generating more and more nested versions of this. I guess if you add a template specialization for the case `N==0` then the recursion stops and it is do-able.

Comment: This actually works `template<> struct call_me_t<0> {  static void exec(int i) { call_me(custom_type<0>()); } };

Comment: Yes, you need a special call_me_t<0> to stop recursion. By the way, in this case event a function template should do the job. I started with the struct because one cannot do partial function template specialization, but here there is nothing partial...

Comment: Oh sorry. I just see you already had that mentioned in the text. Didn't see that.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following:

```
template <std::size_t I>
void call_me_with_custom_type()
{
    call_me(custom_type<I>());
}

namespace detail
{

    template <std::size_t ... Is>
    void foo(std::index_sequence<Is...>, int i)
    {
        std::function<void()> calls[] = {call_me_with_custom_type<Is>...};

        calls[i]();
    }

}

template <std::size_t N>
void foo(int i)
{
    detail::foo(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}, i);
}
```

Comment: I needed some time to wrap my head around this. Now, I think it's a very elegant solution.